# Where do the files created with File.new actually get stored in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am creating files from within Ruby scripts and adding stuff to them. But where are these files stored that I am creating?

I'm very new to this, sorry!

Comment: You should show a sample of the code you're using so we can see how you're creating the files.

Answer (score 2):

The files are created at whatever location you specified. For instance:

```
f = File.new("another_test.txt","w+")
```

that will create the file in the current working directory. You specify the path along with the file name. For example:

```
 f = File.new("~/Desktop/another_test.txt","w+") # will create the file on the desktop.
```

For more details, check the [File documentation.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-new)

**Updated**:
Included mu is too short correction.

Comment: "will create the file in the same directory as the script that contained that code": not quite, that will create the file in the current working directory but that could be pretty much anything since anyone can [`chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) whenever they want.

Comment: @muistooshort you're absolutely right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks very much. I knew it would be something as simple as this! Really appreciate it.